# Dual Coxeter numbers, Langlands dual groups, black holes and twisted compactification of 6d (2,0) A D E theories on a circle

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, quantum-field-theory, modular-representation-theory, geometric-langlands

A 6-dimensional (2,0) superconformal quantum field theory comes in Lie algebra A, D, E types. These theories do not have classical Lagrangian and are purely quantum.These theories on a torus compactification without twisting leads to the 4-dimensional ${\cal N}=4$ supersymmetric Yang-Mills theory of A, D, E, gauge group. The 6-dim theories are known to carry degrees of freedom proportional to the product of the dual Coxeter number of the group  $h^\vee_G$ and the dimension of the group $d_G$.

In our recent study [arXiv:2103.06044](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.06044/) of the black hole entropy in these 6-dim theories with a  twisted circle compactification by outer-automorphism, we have encountered a very simple relation  between the products $h^\vee_Gd_G$  of Lie groups.

For a group $G$ with outer-automorphism, one can associate the Langlands dual group $H^\vee$ of the subgroup $H$ obtained by outer-automorphism twisting of $G$.  The relation we found is
$$ h^\vee_{H^\vee} d_{H^\vee} = \frac{h^\vee_G d_G}{n_G} , $$
where $n_G=2,3,4$. $n_G$ is not exactly the order of outer-automorphism, which is 2 or 3.
The following table shows the above relation holds explicitly.

\begin{array}{||c|c|c|c|c|c||}
G & h^\vee_G & d_G & n_G& H &  H^\vee & h^\vee_{H^\vee} & d_{H^\vee}\\ \hline
A_{2r-1} & 2r & 4r^2-1 & 2 & C_r & B_r & 2r-1 & r(2r+1)\\
A_{2r} & 2r+1 & 4r(r+1) & 4& C'_r & C'_r& r+1 & r(2r+1)\\
D_r & 2(r-1) &  r(2r-1) & 2 & B_{r-1}& C_{r-1} & r & (r-1)(2r-1) \\
D_4 & 6 & 28 & 3 & G_2 & G_2 & 4 & 14 \\
E_6 & 12 & 78 & 2 & F_4 & F_4 & 9 & 52
\end{array}

For the 4-dimensional ${\cal N} =4$ supersymmetric Yang-Mills theory with the gauge group $C_r$ comes in two varieties depending on the range of the $\theta$ parameters. The S-duality leads to either gauge theory of its Langlands dual, $B_r$ or $C_r$.

One question is whether this relation has been noticed before. If so, in what context.  Another is its possible implications in the representation theory.

Comment: In the row of your table with $G=A_{2r}$, if $H=C_r$ shouldn't $H^\vee$ be $B_r$? EDIT: But anyways I didn't think you were really "allowed" to fold an automorphism that fixed an edge but reversed its vertices. E.g. in his note on folding Stembridge disallows this: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~jrs/papers/folding.pdf.

Comment: For the folding of $A_{2r}$ is done physically in our work. I suspect that Stembridge's frame could be extended just enough to accommodate our result.

Comment: The Langlands dual in the sense of 4d S-duality is a bit subtle for the $C_r$ case, depending on the range of the $\theta$ parameter. The 4d $C_r'$ theory is self-dual under the S-duality.

Comment: $n_G$ appears as $c_\sigma$ in (3) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4098v2